# Javascript, using require() and import in the same file

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I need to use require() in my file so I can use 'readline', but I also need to use import so I can use a module. But when I use require inside of my module it says **require is not defined**. Here is the code :

```
var r1 = require('readline')
import car from './carclass.mjs'
var input = ""
var questionToAsk = ""
const question1 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        r1.question(questionToAsk, (answer) => {
            input = answer
            resolve()
        })
        r1.question()
    })
}
const main = async () => {
    console.log("What is the Brand?")
    await question1()
    var brandName = input
    console.log("What is the Model?")
    await question1()
    var modelName = input
    console.log("What is the Speed?")
    await question1()
    var carSpeed = input
    var newCar = new car(brandName,modelName,carSpeed)

    r1.close()
}
main()
```

How can I use require() and import in a module, or is there some other way I can approach this?

Comment: Why don't you `import rl from 'readline'`?

Comment: Because it says r1.question() isn't a function

Comment: I think that's because you were skipping the `.createInterface()` step.  See the working code below in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you just use `import` instead of `require()` if you're already in an ESM module file since `require()` only exists in CJS modules, not ESM modules.  Here's a code example that works:

```
import readline from 'readline';
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("What's up?\n", data => {
    console.log(`Got your result: ${data}`);
    rl.close();
});
```

In node v12.13.1, I run this with this command line:

```
node --experimental-modules temp.mjs
```

FYI, from your comments, it appears you were skipping the `.createInterface()` step.

Answer (score 4):

to use import and require() you can try this

```
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

Use this code on the top of the file in which you want to use 'IMPORT' and 'Require' both